# How to get real T-SQL generated by Entity Framework with ToTraceString() not working

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

```
    //get full list of active employees

    public static object EmployeeList()
    {
        string traceFile = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

        var empList = (from emp in dbViews.EmployeeList
                       where emp.StatusID == 7
                       orderby emp.EmpNo
                       select new  
                       {
                           emp.id, 
                           emp.Name, 
                           emp.EmpNo,
                           emp.Telephone,
                           emp.EmployeeType,
                           emp.DepartmentName,
                           emp.Supervisor,
                           emp.ImmediateSupervisor,
                           emp.StatusID 
                       });

        File.AppendAllText(traceFile, ((ObjectQuery)empList).ToTraceString()); 
        return empList.ToList();
    }
```

When executing the above code, am getting the error below and am not sure why

*

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`9[System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]]'
>   to type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery'.

*

I just want to get the real T-SQL generated by the above Entity Framework code.
The error is at line below

```
File.AppendAllText(traceFile, ((ObjectQuery)empList).ToTraceString());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using DbContext API so you can use just `empList.ToString()`.

Comment: When call .ToString(), i get error "Access to the path 'C:\Users\myUserName\Desktop' is denied."

Comment: That may be problem of your `File.AppendAllText` and permission for your application. It is not related to calling the `ToString` method.